# Coq: Proposition about the contents of a set

Tags: coq

I just started using Coq.

How can I define the proposition `myProp` such that, given a set `H`, `myProp H` is true iff [image: formula] ?

In particular, how can I express the fact that `H` is a subset of `nat` in a proposition? Or how can I simply state *let H be a subset of nat*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are in type theory, so the notion of subset does not exists exactly in the
same manner as in set theory.

Describing something as a subset of nat is just done by by describing it as a proposition over natural numbers.  Something of type `nat -> Prop`.

The sentence *let `H` be a subset of nat* is written:

```
Variable H : nat -> Prop.
```

Now that predicate on natural number can only be applied to natural numbers.

If you want to have uniformity and talk about the full subset of natural numbers, it is represented by (choosing a name at random)

```
Definition all_nat n := True.
```

Turning attention to your `myProp` predicate, it will only be applied on predicates on natural numbers, so you can remove the part about being a subset of nat, which will always be satisfied.

```
Definition myProp (H : nat -> Prop) := forall x, H (2 * x) -> H x.
```

If I really want to have a description following your initial proposal, I would write

```
Definition myProp' (H : nat -> Prop) :=
   (forall x, H x -> all_nat x) /\
   (forall x, H (2 * x) -> H x).
```

But the first part of the conjunct is really useless in the case of `all_nat`.  It might come handy in other cases where you would want to consider all subsets of another meaningful subset of nat.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm just starting with Coq so I was missing some background.

Comment: You could also use the `Ensembles` library which provides wrappers around some of this.  e.g. `Definition myProp (A : Ensemble nat) : Prop := forall n:nat, In _ A (2 * n) -> In _ A n.`

Comment: What I don't like about the Ensembles library is that it loads an axiom.  I prefer not to advertize it.